# Comparing instances of a dict subclass

Tags: python

I have subclassed dict to add an extra method (so no overriding).

Now, I try to compare two of those subclasses, and I get something weird :

```
>>> d1.items() == d2.items()
True
>>> d1.values() == d2.values()
True
>>> d1.keys() == d2.keys()
True
>>> d1 == d2
False
```

**EDIT**

That's damn weird ... I don't understand at all ! Anybody with an insight on how the dict.**eq** is implemented ?

Following is all the code :

```
# ------ Bellow is my dict subclass (with no overriding) :

class ClassSetDict(dict):

    def subsetget(self, klass, default=None):
        class_sets = set(filter(lambda cs: klass <= cs, self))
        # Eliminate supersets
        for cs1 in class_sets.copy():
            for cs2 in class_sets.copy():
                if cs1 <= cs2 and not cs1 is cs2:
                    class_sets.discard(cs2)
        try:
            best_match = list(class_sets)[0]
        except IndexError:
            return default
        return self[best_match]

# ------  Then an implementation of class sets

class ClassSet(object):
    # Set of classes, allowing to easily calculate inclusions
    # with comparison operators : `a < B` <=> "A strictly included in B"

    def __init__(self, klass):
        self.klass = klass

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

    def __gt__(self, other):
        other = self._default_to_singleton(other)
        return not self == other and other < self

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self < other or self == other

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self > other or self == other

    def _default_to_singleton(self, klass):
        if not isinstance(klass, ClassSet):
            return Singleton(klass)
        else:
            return klass


class Singleton(ClassSet):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        other = self._default_to_singleton(other)
        return self.klass == other.klass

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, AllSubSetsOf):
            return issubclass(self.klass, other.klass)
        else:
            return False


class AllSubSetsOf(ClassSet):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, AllSubSetsOf):
            return self.klass == other.klass
        else:
            return False

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, AllSubSetsOf):
            return issubclass(self.klass, other.klass) and not other == self
        else:
            return False

# ------ and finally the 2 dicts that don't want to be equal !!!

d1 = ClassSetDict({AllSubSetsOf(object): (int,)})
d2 = ClassSetDict({AllSubSetsOf(object): (int,)})
```

Comment: It would help to see how you subclassed the `dict`... show us the code! :)

Comment: are `d1` and `d2` of the same type?

Comment: yep same type ... @mac: Yeaaah :) I know ... but it is so funky that I was thinking it's much better if somebody knew it was a general problem ! But OK ... I'll show ...

Comment: phimuemue, that should work anyway. max is right, we need to see the code.

Comment: You must be doing more. Your ClassSetDict cannot show that behavior.

Comment: Everything is there ... I didn't want to post it since it's a fair amount of code, and it's annoying to read !

Comment: That's damn weird ... I don't understand at all ! Anybody with an insight on how the dict.__eq__ is implemented ?

Comment: We are still missing the definition of ClassSet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the problem you're seing has nothing at all to do with subclassing `dict`.  in fact this behavior can be seen using a regular dict.  The problem is how you have defined the *keys* you're using.  A simple class like:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
... 
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return self.value == other.value
...
```

Is enough to demonstrate the problem:

```
>>> f1 = Foo(5)
>>> f2 = Foo(5)
>>> f1 == f2
True
>>> d1 = {f1: 6}
>>> d2 = {f2: 6}
>>> d1.items() == d2.items()
True
>>> d1 == d2
False
```

What's missing is that you forgot to define `__hash__`.  Every time you change the equality semantics of a class, you should make sure that the `__hash__` method agrees with it: when two objects are equal, they must have equal hashes.  `dict` behavior depends *strongly* on the hash value of keys.

When you inherit from `object`, you automatically get both `__eq__` and `__hash__`, the former compares object identity, and the latter returns the address of the object (so they agree), but when you change `__eq__`, you're still seeing the old `__hash__`, which no longer agrees and `dict` gets lost.

Simply provide a `__hash__` method that in a stable way combines the hash values of its attributes.

```
>>> class Bar(object):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
... 
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return self.value == other.value
... 
...     def __hash__(self):
...         return hash((Bar, self.value))
... 
>>> b1 = Bar(5)
>>> b2 = Bar(5)
>>> {b1: 6} == {b2: 6}
True
>>>
```

When using `__hash__` in this way, it's also a good idea to make sure that the attributes do not (or better, cannot) change after the object is created.  If the hash value changes while collected in a dict, the key will be "lost", and all sorts of weird things can happen (even weirder than the issue you initially asked about)

Comment: Well done... I was investigating a totally different line of thinking (the sortability of sets) when I luckily saw your post and saved myself the shame! ;) +1

Comment: Great !!! It works ! One more question though ... Do you think ``hash(self.__class__.__name__) + hash(self.klass)`` is a good hash for ``ClassSet`` ? I am especially wondering about the ``hash(self.klass)`` hashing a class. I remember I had weird behaviour depending on how you import the class :-S

Comment: using `self.__class__` is probably a poor idea if you might use a subclass; the hash value will change (because the type has changed) but the equality won't, and so you're back to square one.  actually spelling out the class is a good way to avoid the problem.  Another solution is to just take the class out of the hash computation totally, but this might lead to undesirable collisions when the attribute (`value` in my example) is itself in the collection.

Comment: (also, you should not use `+` in hash calculations;  combine hash values with `^` to preserve the hash distribution and avoid arithmetic overflow; `__hash__` is not permitted to return `long`)

Comment: Yep ... you're absolutely right ! I'll just add a flag for Set, and a flag for Singleton to the hash, and that should do it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @TokenMacGuy another easy way to combine hash values is to take the hash of a tuple. e.g. `hash((Bar, self.value))` will combine the hashes of `Bar` and `self.value` in a suitable manner that is slightly more complex than a simple xor. That will matter if @sebpiq starts including a couple of boolean flags in the hash. `hash(True)==1, hash(False)==0` so xoring a bunch of flags together wouldn't be a good hash.

Comment: Great ! I'll change my hash function then ... Thanks to you @Duncan and TokenMacGuy !

Answer (score 3):

This most probably depends from some implementation details, in fact a basic subclassing doesn't show this problem:

```
>>> class D(dict):
...    def my_method(self):
...        pass
... 
>>> d1 = D(alpha=123)
>>> d1
{'alpha': 123}
>>> d2 = D(alpha=123)
>>> d1.items() == d2.items()
True
>>> d1.values() == d2.values()
True
>>> d1.keys() == d2.keys()
True
>>> d1 == d2
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Your instance of "AllSubSetsOf" asre used as dict keys -- they should have a **hash** method.
Try adding a

```
def __hash__(self): 
   return hash(self.klass)
```

method to either ClassSet or AllSubSetsOf

Answer (score 1):

I do so hate it when people say things like "The dicts contain funky stuff, so it wouldn't help much to show" since it is precisely the nature of the funky stuff that matters here.

The first thing to note is that if you had exactly the opposite result it wouldn't be surprising at all: i.e. if `d1.items(), d1.values(), d1.keys()` were not equal to `d2.items(), d2.values(), d2.keys()` you could quite happily have `d1 == d2`. That's because dictionaries don't compare by comparing items or keys, they use a different technique which (I think) is the source of your problem.

Effectively comparing two dictionaries first checks they are the same length, then goes through all the keys in the first dictionary to find the smallest one that doesn't match the key/value from the second dictionary. So what we are actually looking for is a case where `d1.keys()==d2.keys()` but for some k either `k not in d1 or k not in d2 or d1[k] != d2[k]`.

I think the clue may be in the objects you are using as dictionary keys. If they are mutable you can store an object in the dictionary but then mutate it and it becomes inaccessible through normal means. The `keys()` method may still find it though and in that case you could get what you are seeing.

Now you've updated the question with the `AllSubSetsOf` class: it is the missing `__hash__()` method that is the problem. Two different instances can compare equal: `AllSubSetsOf(object)==allSubSetsOf(object)` but the hash values are just hashing on the address so they will be different.

```
>>> class AllSubSetsOf(object):
    def __init__(self, klass):
        self.klass = klass

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, AllSubSetsOf):
            return self.klass == other.klass
        else:
            return False

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, AllSubSetsOf):
            return issubclass(self.klass, other.klass) and not other == self
        else:
            return False


>>> a = AllSubSetsOf(object)
>>> b = AllSubSetsOf(object)
>>> a==b
True
>>> hash(a), hash(b)
(2400161, 2401895)
>>>
```